# Laravel application shared hosting, storage folder symbolic Link issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, shared-hosting

I've created symbolic link at local PC, where its working fine, but I've uploaded same it to shared hosting, it is not working there.
Basically I've images in the storage folder `root/storage/public/images/`

i want to display them by getting

```
$path=asset('storage/images/'.$item->image);
```

so the problem is in the shared hosting this way

```
$path=asset('storage/images/'.$item->image);
```

getting from the domain directory not from the parent directory, so for that there is no way to create symbolic link on shared hosting so what should I do to get images from the parent directory.
I am beginner in laravel one can help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: I have detected a thing that should really concern you. You shouldn't have your storage folder under /root since that is the root account's home folder, unless by root you mean the root folder of your Laravel application.

Comment: by root i mean the home folder of my laravel application

Comment: Thank you,I've just created symbolic folder in the website root directory, its working fine for me :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you!

Answer (score 5):

first delete folder storage from folder public and, using this code in web.php

```
Route::get('foo', function(){
    $targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project_foder/laravel/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project_foder/public/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder);
    return 'success';
});
```

or

```
Route::get('foo', function(){
    Artisan::call('storage:link', []);
    return 'success';
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this a solution here

first, delete the public/storage {storage} folder Second, put this code in the top of the web.php file

```
Artisan::call('storage:link');
```

this code runs the  php artisan storage:link command manually

Answer (score 1):

Please create link folder with storage folder that will create same folder in the project file library. For further information, 
[Symbolic links using PHP](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihwfaczs_YAhVC7xQKHV39B1AQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcworld.idg.com.au%2Farticle%2F191942%2Fsymbolic_links_using_php%2F&usg=AOvVaw0vO_dsZTeOPygMi2CS67Ig)